# How to continuously add numbers?

Tags: python, loops

I don't know how to continuously add numbers. I want to find out how to ask the user for integer, then add a specific number and continue by adding numbers until stopped. (Python 3.8)

This is all I got so far.

```
n = input("Enter Number to calculate sum")
n = int (n)
sum = 0
for num in range(0, n+1, 1):
    sum = sum+num
print("SUM of first ", n, "numbers is: ", sum )
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. You want to add all numbers up a certain number: { 0, 1, 2 ... n}?

Comment: What is the problem with the code in your question? Doesn't that already satisfy your need?

Answer (score 0):

```
sum = 0

while condition:
    sum += int(input())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sum_ = 0
while True:
    i = input("Enter a number, or press enter to exit: ")
    if not i:
        break
    sum_ += int(i)
print(sum_)
```